# Could not post data with Python

Tags: python, authentication, http-post

This is what I have so far. I am attempting to login and view the members page but I can't seem to accomplish that. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
import requests 

s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://theocarinanetwork.com/login'                    
uname = 'USERNAME'                                                               
pw = 'PASSWORD'  
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',                  
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',                     
           'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'}

data = {'uname':uname,                                                          
        'pw':pw,                                                        
        'submit':'button',                                          
        'base_uri':'http://theocarinanetwork.com/index'} 
response = s.post(url, headers = headers)

if response.status_code == 200: 
response = s.get('http://theocarinanetwork.com/members/')

print response.text
```

Comment: You are not using `data` anywhere.

Comment: According to the HTML source of the page you are trying to POST to the actual login URL is http://theocarinanetwork.com/login/log_in/. I also see a hidden `tm` field; did you check how that is used by the form?

Comment: Also: print the response's status code and body instead of assuming you should have a 200...

Comment: You know.... I honestly just completely missed that. Thank you I have it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 

s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://theocarinanetwork.com/login/log_in'                    
uname = '******'                                                               
pw = '******'  
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',                  
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',                     
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'}
data = {'uname':uname,                                                          
    'pw':pw,                                                        
    'submit':'button',                                          
    'base_uri':'http://theocarinanetwork.com/index'}

response = s.post(url, data, headers = headers)

if response.status_code == 200: 
    response = s.get('http://theocarinanetwork.com/members/')
    print response.text
```